# Time effciency for test case in euler #1

Tags: time-complexity, big-o

In solving competitive programming problem what are the things we need to consider to solve a problem in time efficient way?

For instance, in one problem, [Project Euler Multiples of 3 and 5](https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/projecteuler/challenges/euler001/submissions/code/3629090) Code runs in O(n^2). This is considering the loop for taking the test cases.

Questions:

1. Why does the code time out in this problem?
2. How can I make my code efficient?

The description of the question is in the link.

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;


int main() {
    /* Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT */  
    int t, n; 
    int n1,n2; 
    int mul3, mul5, sum=0,sum3=0,sum5=0;
    cin>> t;

    while(t--){

        cin>>n; 
        sum=0;
        sum5=0;
        sum3=0; 

        if(n%3==0)
                n1=n/3-1; 
        else
               n1=n/3; 

        if(n%5==0)
                n2=n/5-1; 
        else
            n2=n/5; 

        for(int i=0;i<=n1;i++){
            if(i<=n2){
                mul5= i*5; 
                sum5+=mul5;
            }
            mul3=i*3;
            if((mul3%5)!=0) 
            sum3+=mul3; 
            sum = sum3+sum5; 
        }
        cout << sum << endl; 

    }
    system("PAUSE"); 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If the program works already, what about posting it at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Solving something [that is O(1)](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/86127/31562) in O(n^2)? Impressive.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to iterate over all numbers and you definitely can't afford to perform n^2 operations for `n=10^9`. The correct solutions requires a little knowledge of number theory and of the count of numbers divisible by a given value. Can you figure out a way to compute the count of numbers divisible by 5 up to `X`? Try to do that with constant complexity. Then do something similar for the numbers divisible by 3 and apply the inclusion-exclusion principle.

Please note: optimizing your code no matter how well will only improve its performance marginally. Changing the algorithm on the other hand may change its complexity orders of magnitude.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe having a little look here will help you get a O(1) solution [Inclusion–exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle). 
For this problem set `A` consists of numbers divisible by `3`, set `B` consists of numbers divisible by `5`. And `A∩B` consists of numbers that are divisible by both `3 and 5`. So ,

```
A={3,6,9,...,999}
```

This forms an arithmetic series. You can find the sum of this using standard formula. Do the same for other 2 sets and you are done.

Comment: I did the same using Arithmetic progression concept